# Displaying a large image in a ScrollViewer in another ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll

Following on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002254/displaying-a-large-image-in-scrollviewer-in-wpf) I am now trying to display an Image in a ScrollViewer that is positioned inside another ScrollViewer.

The image is again a large one 2000x2000 pixels.

The main UI is a DockPanel which has a title TextBlock in the Top panel.  The filled panel is a ScrollViewer which I refer to as the outside ScrollViewer.

Inside the outside ScrollViewer, I have a Grid named MainContentGrid which has 2 columns - both need to be 50% available width.  In column 1 we have some TextBlocks.  In column 2 I am trying to display the large image that will exceed the ActualWidth of column 2.  This is wrapped in a ScrollViewer which I refer to as the internal ScrollViewer.

When I run the following code, the outside ScrollViewer has the active scroll bars which scrolls the entire MainContentGrid which is not what I want.  I am trying to get the internal ScrollViewer have the scrollbars active for the Image.

So what I see initially is:

[image: Top Left Image]

Then when I scroll down and right, I can see the Crimson Button (with the Browse button) Stack Panel inside the scroll region:

[image: Bottom Right]

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfIssues.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfIssues"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Background="CadetBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="Test Image" FontSize="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></TextBlock>

        <!-- this is the outside scroller -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid x:Name="MainContentGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- this is a left hand panel which may have content bigger than than the 
                     window which i will want to scroll the entire content (including the right hand panel which
                    hosts the other scroll viewer)
                -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock>Hello there</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>mary doll</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <!-- This is the right hand side photo panel -->
                <DockPanel x:Name="PhotoPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  Background="Crimson">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button Click="Button_Click">Browse...</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- This is the internal scroll panel.  this should just scroll make image scroll
                    -->
                    <ScrollViewer 
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                Background="Transparent">
                        <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" 
                                Stretch="Uniform" 
                                Source="Resources/bear grills.png"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**UPDATE**
If I add a Height and Width to the internal ScrollViewer then I get the scrollbars around the image.

Is it possible to make the internal ScrollViewer "fit" to the DockPanel named PhotoPanel?

Comment: @ChrisW.- Didn't work.  The scrollable region still remains around the main grid in the outside ScrollViewer.

Comment: So you're saying, when you focus on the inner scrollviewer, it doesn't scroll but the outer one does instead? So your problem here (after actually looking at your snip :) is there's no boundary to define when the inner scrollviewer should even invoke since as far as it's concerned, it has plenty of space thanks to your outer scrollviewer. You have to provide some sort of boundary to invoke your inner scrollviewer to even become active. Be that a fixed size, or disabling a direction or something, that's up to you. However you will not get your desired result as it sits.

Comment: @ChrisW. - I've shortened the example.  Nothing to do with focus.  When the window is displayed, the scrollable region is the outside scroll viewer.  I only want this to scroll when the vertical height is bigger than the available area - ie where I have the TextBlocks (hello mary doll).  However, the image I have is larger than the space on the right, but I just want the internal ScrollViewer to scroll around that.  Hope it makes sense.  Just reworded the question.

Comment: Ok, so let's look at this. Outside scrollviewer is set to Auto/Auto, right? So the inner ScrollViewer is basically going "Uh, why am I even here dude? You can scroll however you want in either direction anyway..." right? Maybe if I saw a visual of the UX you're shooting for I could just give you a better solution. Except I'm already abusing the hell out of the comments section lol.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have updated the question and added screenshots.  I have added a Height and Width to the internal ScrollViewer which makes the scrollbars appear around the image.  Ideally I think I need to somehow make the ScrollViewer maximise in the space available in the DockPanel?

Comment: I don't get it, why is the outer ScrollView even there if you don't actually want all that other stuff to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you right in visualizing what you want your actual output to be like. We can ditch your extra ScrollViewer, and your DockPanel, and just keep it as simple as it can get like this. Just del everything you got in there and replace it with this snip and see if it's more in line of what you're shooting for;

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!-- Because we want some accent colors -->
  <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="CadetBlue"/>
  <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="CadetBlue"/>
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Crimson"/>

  <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Test Image" FontSize="30" />

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock>Hello there</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>mary doll</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" 
           Stretch="Uniform" 
           Source="Resources/bear grills.png"/>
  </ScrollViewer>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
              Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Browse...</Button>
  </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I only took a minute before I leave the office for the day so hopefully I didn't forget anything but I'm a big fan of the "K.I.S.S." ideology, and I'm not such a fan for dirty D.O.M.'s and unnecessarily heavy templates used like DockPanel, so hopefully it still aligns with what you're trying to accomplish. If not, I'm on here pretty much every workday anyway for fun. Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: The only problem with this is if I fill up the left hand column with TextBlocks, then there is no way to scroll it if the viewing area is not big enough.  I have come up with a solution below which "works" but I am not convinced at the minute.  Have a look and see what you think

Answer (score 0):

This will work providing a scrollable view if the left hand column is bigger.  I don't think its 100% correct and could be improved:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfIssues.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfIssues"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Background="CadetBlue" LastChildFill="True">
            <TextBlock Text="Test Image" FontSize="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></TextBlock>

            <!-- this is the outside scroller -->
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Grid x:Name="MainContentGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- this is a left hand panel which may have content bigger than than the 
                             window which i will want to scroll the entire content (including the right hand panel which
                            hosts the other scroll viewer)
                        -->
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock>Hello there</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 1</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 2</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 3</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 4</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 5</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 6</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 7</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 8</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 9</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 10</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 11</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 12</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 13</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 14</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 15</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 16</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 17</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 18</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 19</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 20</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 21</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 22</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 23</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 24</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 25</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 26</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 27</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 28</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Line 29</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- This is the right hand side photo panel -->
                    <Grid x:Name="PhotoPanel" Grid.Column="1">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- This is the internal scroll panel.  this should just scroll make image scroll
                            -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ImageGrid">
                            <ScrollViewer 
                                          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ImageGrid, Mode=OneWay}"
                                          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ImageGrid, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" 
                                        Source="Resources/bear grills.png"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Background="Crimson" Grid.Row="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Button Click="Button_Click">Browse...</Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```